# Add code with AddJar() when using streams API?

Tags: java, hazelcast-jet

How can I use the addJar() method when I implement a stream?

The newJob() uses a DAG:

```
JobConfig config = new JobConfig();
config.addJar("..");
jet.newJob(dag, config).execute().get();
```

Streams are changed to DAGs internally:

```
IMap<String, Long> counts = lines
                .stream()
                .flatMap(..);
```

Comment: The Jet streams API doesn't currently support this. I've createn an issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/issues/353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible as of version 0.4

```
IStreamMap<Integer, Integer> map = jet.getMap(randomString());
range(0, 10).parallel().forEach(i -> map.put(i, i));

JobConfig jobConfig = new JobConfig();
jobConfig.addClass(MyMapper.class);
List<Integer> list = map
    .stream()
    .configure(jobConfig)
    .map(new MyMapper())
    .collect(toList());
```